# CloudWatch Logs insights Query to Get count of Given strings

Tags: amazon-web-services, statistics, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have a CloudWatch log group that contains log statements in bulk, here I want to filter the logs which contain the string `"ABC"`.

Then I want the count of `"XYZ"`, `"PQR"`,

My current approach:

```
fields @message
| filter @message like /ABC/
| filter @message like /XYZ/
| stats count() as XYZ_COUNT
```

```
fields @message
| filter @message like /ABC/
| filter @message like /PQR/
| stats count() as PQR_COUNT
```

Can we achieve it in a single query instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After digging the docs I got the way we can do it, here it is.

```
fields @message
| filter @message like /ABC/
| parse @message 'XYZ' as @xyz
| parse @message 'PQR' as @pqr
| stats count(@xyz) as XYZ_COUNT, count(@pqr) as PQR_COUNT
```

Let me know if any better approach is there.